# mocha/chai.js testing harness: https calls do not work from after() function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

```
mocha.js:  3.4.2
chai.js:   4.1.0
node.js:   6.10.3
npm:       5.3.0
```

I've set up a simple test harness for a RESTful service deployed under node.js.  The test harness relies on `mocha.js / chai.js`.  Each test, which calls an endpoint through https, works.  As well, `before()` and `after()`
functions are called.  HOWEVER:  it appears impossible to invoke any of the RESTful endpoints within the `after()` function.  Why?

Since `after()` comes at the end of the tests, I thought the asynchronous invocation of the RESTful endpoint simply had no time to return before the test process exited.  So, I encoded a busy-wait loop to give the response some time.  No go:  the endpoint invocation simply does not work in `after()`.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "so-mcv-example",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "restify": "^4.3.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "6.10.3",
        "npm": "5.3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "chai": "^4.1.0",
        "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
        "mocha": "^3.4.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha"
    }
}
```

My `index.js` looks like this:

```
const restify = require('restify'),
           fs = require('fs');

const server = restify.createServer({
    certificate: fs.readFileSync('security/server.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('security/server.key'),
    name: 'so-mcv-example'
});

server.listen(443, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});

server.pre(restify.pre.userAgentConnection());

server.get('/status', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send({ status: 'so-mcv-example is running ok.' });
    return next();
});
```

Under `test` directory, I have `mocha.opts`:

```
--require ./test/test.bootstrap
```

and `test.bootstrap.js`:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

// CAUTION: never do this in production! For testing purposes, we ignore
// faults in the standard SSL handshaking.
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

The latter settings negotiate the self-signed SSL certificate employed in `index.js`.  In `test/status-test.js`, I have:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const should = chai.should();
const server = 'https://localhost';

chai.use(require('chai-http'));

before(function() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV != "test") {
        this.skip();
    }

    // XXX Wipe the database.
    console.log("Wipe the database BEFORE tests.");
});

describe('GET /status', function() {
    it('passes, as expected', function(done) {
        chai.request(server)
        .get('/status')
        .end(function(err, res) {
            expect(err).to.be.null;
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});

after(function() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV != "test") {
        this.skip();
    }

    chai.request(server)
    .get('/status')
    .end(function(err, res) {
        expect(err).to.be.null;
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        console.log("2nd call to /status returned.");
        done();
    });
});
```

Admittedly, using `chai` to invoke an endpoint in the `after()` function is contrived.  That's not the point.  The point is that the `console.log()` directive simply is never executed.  That is, when I run `npm test`, the result is:

```
> so-mcv-example@1.0.0 test /Users/charlie/workspace/so-mcv-mocha
> mocha



Wipe the database BEFORE tests.
  GET /status
    ✓ passes, as expected (44ms)


  1 passing (56ms)
```

See my answer below for an explanation about why `console.log()` is not executed.

To resolve the issue, I added a the option `--no-exit` to `mocha.opts`:

```
--require ./test/test.bootstrap
--no-exit
```

Then when I run `npm test`, the desired result is output:

```
> so-mcv-example@1.0.0 test /Users/charlie/workspace/so-mcv-mocha
> mocha



Wipe the database BEFORE tests.
  GET /status
    ✓ passes, as expected (43ms)


  1 passing (55ms)

2nd call to /status returned.
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see your testing code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution.  In `after()`, if you asynchronously invoke some endpoint on a service external to your testing environment, then that asynchronous call is queued and not immediately executed.  This is the nature of calling asynchronous functions in node.js.  Well, if there is no logic after the `after()` call, then `mocha` immediately exits by invoking `process.exit()`!  The end-result is that your asynchronous call to an external endpoint remains queued and never invoked.

Resolution:  inside `mocha.opts` under your `test` directory, just install the option `--no-exit`.

Comment: There could very well be better options than using `--no-exit` but we're not going to know until the question is edited to include a [mcve].

Comment: Per your request, I went ahead and added an example to my notes.  Please add points back to my question.  And if you provide a better answer, I'll review and score it accordingly.